# How do select certain column indexes (continuous and individual) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I come from an R background and am having trouble slicing certain sets of columns in pandas.

Let's say I am trying to get the columns with index 0, 3, 5 through 20, and 25th. I would think the way to access what I want is:

`df.iloc[:, [0,3,5:20,25]]`

but there is a syntax error with the `:` within the `5:20` line of code. Is there a way to generate a sequence of numbers from 5 through 20 without typing each number out?

Comment: Hi, this is not efficient but it worked. `result = pd.concat([df.iloc[[0,3]], df.iloc[5:20], df.iloc[[25]]], axis=0)`

Comment: Please provide input, output, and desired output samples as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to post great questions. Help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.r_[...]`:

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[0,3,5:21,25]]
```

Notice that the slice is `5:21` since numpy uses Python's slicing convention (exclude the upperbound) while pandas includes both the lower and upperbound.

Answer (score 1):

You could build the list first and then use `.iloc[]` with it.

```
my_list = [0, 3]
my_list.extend(range(5, 21))
my_list.extend([25])
df.iloc[my_list]
```